# JavaFX slows down backend

Tags: performance, memory, javafx

This is a school project. We built a JavaFX GUI to take inputs for an algorithm. The algorithm runs only 45 minutes in stand-alone mode. However, when calling from JavaFX GUI, the running time is doubled. Any idea what might cause this? Also, the JavaFX GUI consumes about 400 Mb memory, is this normal?

Any help is appreciated.

Yulian

Comment: Some more information would be helpful. Where you able to generate a minimal, complete and verifiable example? Personally for me it would help to know whether you call the algorithm on the main thread or on a background thread. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The algorithm is called on the main thread, in the button click method.

Comment: I am not sure if that causes the problems, it may since it is a special thread and can have some overhead. generally it is not a good idea to run computation intensive algorithms on the main thread. Makes the UI freeze. So you might want to try to run it in a background thread

Comment: Did you try use priority for threads ?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm and the GUI draw calls are competing for memory and this will create a slowdown for both the algorithm and the gui.

Allocate more memory for the java runtime to fix this

Comment: Wouldn't the algorithm just block the main thread and the guild would freeze? Hence no guild calls that compete for computation time or?

Answer (score -1):

There are very minute things that one needs to keep in mind while developing if they need to optimize their JavaFX Applications (performance wise):

**1.** Many people think that they should write the entire application using pure JavaFX coding. This may be fine for small test applications. But when we write real-world applications, we need to divide the I/O portion, Business logic and all Non-UI related code to different layers.

**2.**
 Use [JavaFx Api Async](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.async/javafx.async.JavaTaskBase.html) + Callback methods so as to execute these code outside Event-Dispatch-Thread.